# What would be possible reasons for Russia splitting into East and West?

Tags: alternate-history, earth

I'm designing an alternate history that centers around an event known as the 'Russian Separation War', where Russia splits into two halves, East and West.

EDIT: This is based in modern times (i.e. 21st Century)

Comment: War by mostly the sword or word?

Comment: This will be very opinion-based. When do you want this split to occur? Today, last century, Mongol times?

Comment: The event will be set in modern times (i.e. 21st century).

Comment: Russia acquired her Asiatic territory relatively recently, beginning with the [conquest of the Khanate of Sibir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conquest_of_the_Khanate_of_Sibir) by Yermak Timofeyevich in 1582. (The Khanate of Sibir was a Turkic state just east of the Urals.) Then, during the [Russian Civil War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian_Civil_War), the eastern part of the country was at war with the Bolshevik dominated western part; maybe instead of losing, [Kolchak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_Kolchak) forced the Bolsheviks to accept the divison?

Comment: Please edit the question and specify that you are asking about the 21st century. You do understand that as it is today, more than 80% of the population of Russia is in the European part of the country? The eastern part would have no chance in a civil war. And if you are serious about "halves" the border would be somewhere along the Yenisei river, making the eastern half contain about 5% of the people of Russia. Much more likely to see the eastern half annexed by the Chinese empire than imagine a successfull secession.

Comment: No, the halves are not literal, but splitting into two independent states.

Comment: Ah, splitting into states. But it *actually did* split into three states, [Great Russia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Russia) (*Velikorossiya*), [Little Russia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little_Russia) (*Malorossiya*, aka Ukraine) and White Russia (*Belorossiya* aka Belarus). It happened in 1990. And at present there is a shooting [war between Great Russia and Little Russia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian_military_intervention_in_Ukraine_(2014%E2%80%93present)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a long and successful reign, Vladimir Putin dies. This immediately throws Russia into a political turmoil. There is a number of potential successors, but no one seems to get an upper hand.

Eventually, opponents consolidate into two groups: "Metropolitan" and "Provincial". Metropolitan group includes politicians and businessmen from Moscow and westernmost part of Russia. Provincial group includes pretty much everyone else, notably North Caucasus and Siberia.

Provincial group had managed to win presidential elections, but Muscovites are starting civil disobedience campaign that evolves into a full revolt. Part of the army stays with the president, while the other part declares for the Moscow. New president escapes to the East and consolidates his power there, while Moscow forms an alternative government. War breaks out, and, for a while, almost all of the Russia is engulfed in it. After some time it becomes clear that neither side is winning the war. In the meantime, Russia is becoming very weak economically and its warring parts are becoming increasingly dependent on foreign help - US/European for Metropolitan fraction and Chinese - for the Provincial one.

Finally, a peace treaty is signed, and two parts of Russia are moving on as independent countries.

P.S. This is a possible, but not likely scenario. While some regions and autonomous republics of Russia may be quick to splinter away, the regions dominated by ethnic Russians are very unlikely to do so, they will be looking for a compromise even if it means that their interests would be hurt.